# Filter an array by NOT containing string (swift 2)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I am relatively new to swift; I am working on filtering arrays.
I know how to filter out elements of an array that contain a letter (like so: `let filteredList = wordlist.filter { !$0.characters.contains(letter) }`), but how do I filter out elements that do not have a letter?
Here's what I want to accomplish:
I have a word list in string-array format, i.e. ["thing", "other thing"] (but much longer), and I want to return every element that has a certain letter, filtering out the ones that do not have a certain letter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear, you want to filter out all the words containing certain character like for example `"e"`?

Comment: @Eendje I want to filter out all the words that do not have a certain character like "e". So, if the input was `["hello", "ok"]`, it would return `hello` because it contains e, and remove ok because it contains e.

Comment: Then, what's wrong with the example you have in your question? Removing the `!` mark will just give the result you want.

Comment: @Eendje Oh, ok. Hehe. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a silly question, I am sorry. Anyway, I just needed to remove the exclamation mark. So...

```
let filteredList = wordlist.filter { !$0.characters.contains(letter) } 
// returns elements in the array WITHOUT "letter".
let filteredList = wordlist.filter { $0.characters.contains(letter) }  
// returns elements in the array WITH "letter".
```

Thanks Eendje.

Comment: You're welcome. But to be honest, that's the whole point of the `!` mark :).